Prerequisites - need to install to run confluent Kafka producer/consumer on server
I have a Windows service developed on .NET 6 which runs on Visual Studio 2022 having confluent Kafka nuget package installed and working fine in local.
But the same .exe (along with dlls) is not able to consume messages in server (Windows). Do we need to install anything on the server before running this service?
